# Können Adjektive und Adverbien teil der Satzklammer sein?

Tags: sentence-structure, adjective, adverb

Laut der Webseite deutschegrammatik20.de können Adjektive und Adverbien Teil der Satzklammer sein. Leider habe ich im Internet keine gute Erklärung dafür gefunden. Die Beispiele sind folgende:

> Ich bin nicht sportlich.
>
> Ich singe nicht gut.

Meine Grammatikerkenntnis sagt mir, dass im rechten Satzklammerteil nur Verben, Präpositionen von trennbaren Verben, und Präpositionalobjekte möglich sind.

Comment: Ich finde die Beispiele sehr kurz, um von linker und rechter Satzklammer zu sprechen. Gibt es längere Beispielsätze, um das Ende einer Satzklammer deutlicher zu machen, die die gleiche Problemstellung zeigen?

Comment: Was ist mit "rechtem Satzklammerteil" gemeint?

Comment: @RHa Deutsche Sätze funktionieren im Bezug auf das Feldermodell: Vorfeld, linke Satzklammer, Mittelfeld, rechte Satzklammer, Nachfeld.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm vermutlich kann es ja mehrere Beispiele geben, aber bisher habe ich nur diese zwei Sätze bei deutschegrammatik20.de gefunden. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da brauch man doch nur weitere Satzteile hinzufügen und schauen, was sich bewegen lässt.

z.B.

> Ich bin morgens um 6 in Berlin nicht sportlich.

z.B.

> Ich singe morgens um 6 in Berlin nicht gut.

Jetzt zeigt sich die Satzklammer schon eher. Man kann "morgens um 6" oder "in Berlin" ans Satzende packen.

Comment: Gegenfragen sind nicht sehr hilfreich. Eine gute Antwort enthält eine Erklärung, evtl. mit 'nem Link, und zeigt Geduld mit den Leuten die hier fragen. Es sind eh wenige ... meint ein freundlicher a_donda :-) Um die Gegenfrage zu beantworten: man kann. Hilft es dem Fragesteller ? Weiß ich nicht ...